# Cocos2d-x removeChild works wierd

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I've got this lines of code

```
for (auto view : views)
{
    view->update(deltaTime);

    if (view->isDead())
    {
        trash.push_back(view);
        removeChild(view, true);
    }
}
```

And it breaks at `removeChild(view, true);` line.

This is my stack trace.

```
 ucrtbased.dll!00007ffab25ac2f1()    Unknown
    ucrtbased.dll!00007ffab25af8a5()    Unknown
    TankGame.exe!operator delete(void * block) Line 21  C++
    TankGame.exe!operator delete(void * block, unsigned __int64 __formal) Line 16   C++
    TankGame.exe!WorldModel::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int) C++
    TankGame.exe!std::_Ref_count<WorldModel>::_Destroy() Line 153   C++
    TankGame.exe!std::_Ref_count_base::_Decref() Line 113   C++
    TankGame.exe!std::_Ptr_base<WorldModel>::_Decref() Line 339 C++
    TankGame.exe!std::shared_ptr<WorldModel>::~shared_ptr<WorldModel>() Line 567    C++
    TankGame.exe!std::shared_ptr<WorldModel>::operator=(std::shared_ptr<WorldModel> && _Right) Line 555 C++
    TankGame.exe!ZombieModel::~ZombieModel() Line 14    C++
    [External Code] 
>   TankGame.exe!ZombieView::~ZombieView() Line 11  C++
    [External Code] 
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Ref::release() Line 138    C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Node * __ptr64>::erase(__int64 index) Line 443 C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Node::detachChild(cocos2d::Node * child, __int64 childIndex, bool doCleanup) Line 1119 C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Node::removeChild(cocos2d::Node * child, bool cleanup) Line 1020   C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Sprite::removeChild(cocos2d::Node * child, bool cleanup) Line 778  C++
    TankGame.exe!WorldView::update(float deltaTime) Line 51 C++
    TankGame.exe!GameScene::update(float deltaTime) Line 55 C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Scheduler::scheduleUpdate::__l2::<lambda>(float dt) Line 285   C++
    [External Code] 
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Scheduler::update(float dt) Line 861   C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Director::drawScene() Line 274 C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::DisplayLinkDirector::mainLoop() Line 1397  C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::GLViewImpl::OnRendering() Line 482 C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::GLViewImpl::Render() Line 474  C++
    TankGame.exe!Cocos2dRenderer::Draw(int width, int height, float dpi, Windows::Graphics::Display::DisplayOrientations orientation) Line 137  C++
    TankGame.exe!CocosAppWinRT::OpenGLESPage::StartRenderLoop::__l2::<lambda>(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^ action) Line 272  C++
    [External Code]
```

And I can't get what it wants from me. It calls a view destructor and that's it! Bam! Crashed! Destructor of the view is empty, and I'm completly lost.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you've called the code for multiple times.

Then auto view is already deleted after you called removeChild(view, true) once, and you have not remove the view from views. Of course the program will crash when you do it trice, for you are trying to remove a view which is already deleted.

If my guess is wrong, you need to post more of your code.

P.S:
Your code style is not very good in Cocos2d-x. You do not need to collect trash like Java. You need to study memory management in Cocos2d-x.